# DOMDocument behaviour differs on various PHP configurations

Tags: php, docker

Here's a code example which behaves differently with

- `phpbrew's php 7.1.5`
- `docker container with php 7.1.15`

  ```
  $elementMarkup = '
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  </html>
  ';
  ```

  $DOMDocument = new DOMDocument;

  $elementMarkup = mb_convert_encoding($elementMarkup, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

  $DOMDocument->loadHTML($elementMarkup);

  $DOMDocument->removeChild($DOMDocument->doctype);

  $DOMDocument->replaceChild($DOMDocument->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $DOMDocument->firstChild);

The incorrect behavior appears to `$DOMDocument->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild`
It should be `meta`(Nodenames from xdebug: html-head-meta) and phpbrew's php works fine.

But dockerized php cathes `null`(Nodenames: html-#text-null).

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN apk upgrade --update && apk --no-cache add \
    bash nodejs autoconf file g++ gcc binutils isl libatomic libc-dev musl-dev make re2c libstdc++ libgcc libcurl \
    curl-dev binutils-libs mpc1 mpfr3 gmp libgomp coreutils freetype-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libltdl libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng-dev openssl-dev libxml2-dev expat-dev icu-dev libxslt libxslt-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mysqli pdo pdo_mysql curl bcmath mcrypt mbstring json xml zip opcache intl xsl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN apk --no-cache add libintl gettext-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gettext

RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && echo no | pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Using `->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild` is potentially a fragile way of doing this anyway.

Comment: @NigelRen this code was taken from a library widely using https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra/blob/0db5cce7354e4b76f155d092ab5eb3981c21258c/ParsedownExtra.php#L473 I agree that the code looks strange. More than that this thing crashes October CMS mailing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about `libxml2`.

I can see people voting the question, so I found [Github issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/612#issuecomment-550315104) I opened then.

To get a predictable result you may call `loadHTML(..., LIBXML_NOBLANKS)`